# Linking a jsp page to a java class

Tags: java, jsp

I have written a hello world program in jsp and now i am trying to process forms via JSP.

My jsp form(GetName.jsp) looks like this

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>


<FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="SaveName.jsp">
Name <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME=username SIZE=20><BR>
Email <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME=email SIZE=20><BR>
Age <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME=age SIZE=4>
<P><INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT>
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
    </body>
</html>
```

Similarly SaveName.jsp looks like this

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <jsp:useBean id="userData" class="javabeans.UserData" scope="session"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="userData" property="*"/> 


</BODY>
</HTML>
    </body>
</html>
```

And in the same project in a package named javabeans the class named UserData looks like this.

```
package javabeans;

public class UserData {

    String username;
    String email;
    int age;

    public void setUsername( String value )
    {
        username = value;
    }

    public void setEmail( String value )
    {
        email = value;
    }

    public void setAge( int value )
    {
        age = value;
    }

    public String getUsername() { return username; }

    public String getEmail() { return email; }

    public int getAge() { return age; }

}
```

Now when  run GetName.jsp i get the following errors

```
D:\javaworkspace\Netbeans7-2\HelloWeb\build\generated\src\org\apache\jsp\SaveName_jsp.java:56: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class UserData
location: class org.apache.jsp.SaveName_jsp
      UserData user = null;
      ^
D:\javaworkspace\Netbeans7-2\HelloWeb\build\generated\src\org\apache\jsp\SaveName_jsp.java:58: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class UserData
location: class org.apache.jsp.SaveName_jsp
        user = (UserData) _jspx_page_context.getAttribute("user", PageContext.SESSION_SCOPE);
D:\javaworkspace\Netbeans7-2\HelloWeb\build\generated\src\org\apache\jsp\SaveName_jsp.java:60: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class UserData
location: class org.apache.jsp.SaveName_jsp
          user = new UserData();
3 errors
D:\javaworkspace\Netbeans7-2\HelloWeb\nbproject\build-impl.xml:930: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\javaworkspace\Netbeans7-2\HelloWeb\nbproject\build-impl.xml:284: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Comment: why are you sending the form data to jsp.. u can use a servlet and from there set the parameters to the Userdata class , and for displaying them use this class as a bean in the jsp

Comment: I am extremely new to jsp.So i am just randomly checking out how to process forms.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import `UserData` class inside SaveName.jsp

Add this to the top of your jsp code in SaveName.jsp

```
<%@ page import="javabeans.UserData" %>
```

Comment: is your `UserData` .class file under `your_webapp/WEB-INF/classes/javabeans` folder ?

Comment: No it isnot.Perhaps i should try to change it.Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to implement over here but i can give you simple idea about jsp servlets

first you can create a simple jsp program. it will ask the user for name and email id and on form action redirect it to abc servlet.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"  
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title> My first JSP   </title>
</head> 
<body>      
    <form action="abc">         
         Please enter a name <br>
        <input type="text" name="name"size="20px">
                     Please enter an email <br>
        <input type="text" name="email"size="20px">
        <input type="submit"     value="submit">                        
    </form>     
</body> 
</html>
```

and then create the "abc" servlet
place this code in your servlet. it will get the value from jsp page and display it.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class abc extends HttpServlet { 
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
  HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
  {
// reading the user input
String name= request.getParameter("name");    
String email= request.getParameter("email");    
String msg="I'm"+name+"id is"+email;
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println (
  "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" 
      \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\">\n" +
  "<html> \n" +
    "<head> \n" +
      "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; 
        charset=ISO-8859-1\"> \n" +
      "<title> Hi </title> \n" +
    "</head> \n" +
    "<body> \n" +
    msg +
      "</font> \n" +
    "</body> \n" +
  "</html>" 
        );  
   }  
 }
```

Define your servlet in "web.xml" . you need to do servlet mapping in web.xml file.

```
   <servlet>
<servlet-name>abc</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>abc</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>abc</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/abc</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```